# Is there a way to automatically rollout latest AMI to EKS clusters in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks, amazon-ami

```
data "aws_ami" "eks_golden_ami"{
  most_recent = true
  owners = ["<account id"]
  filter {
    name = "name"
    value = "*eks*"
}
```

Using this data source we can use latest golden ami while provisioning EKS clusters.

But after the EKS cluster gets created, we would be creating another golden ami in another couple of months. Is there a way to automatically rollout the latest ami into existing clusters?

Answer (score 1):

Presumed you are using self managed node group, else if this is managed node group, the process is largely automated by EKS already. There are many ways to perform self managed node group upgrade, simplest is probably using [eksctl](https://eksctl.io/usage/nodegroup-upgrade/) if you don't need any control over the change. terraform module typically create new node group and destroy existing node group. You can trigger these commands to run upon your new AMI is ready. You can also start with the [golden ami pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/awsmarketplace/announcing-the-golden-ami-pipeline/) and extend with your own deployment steps or the commands above, or customize even more with [Amazon EKS One Click Upgrade](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-eks-one-click-cluster-upgrade).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am using EKS managed nodegroups. I have a couple of dozens of clusters. Just curious to know if there's a way to push a new ami to all the dozen clusters in one go.